# Does /templates route reserved for internal use in ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-razor

Tried to write service to work with following RequestDTO

```
    [Route("/templates", "POST", Summary = "Creates new template")]
    public class CreateTemplate : IReturn<ExecutionResult>
    {
        public Guid TemplateId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string DefaultContent { get; set; }

    }
```

But ServiceStack returns "Static File '/templates/' not found." As far as I can see /Templates folder can be used to define templates for /metadata. But I do not have such folder at all.

Comment: I have just tested this and confirm the same result. As you have indicated it is [related to templating the meta data feature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Templates/HtmlTemplates.cs). It's notable that removing the meta data feature doesn't fix this. For the moment it does appear this route is therefore reserved, but I'd be surprised if a new update of ServiceStack didn't address this in the near future.

Comment: This seems to be the case for "js" as well